# How to disable SMTP Auth Plain for James-2.3.2. on Slackware 14.0?

Tags: slackware, smtp, ssmtp

I am trying to disable SMTP Auth plain for James-2.3.2 on Slackware 14.0.  Has anyone successfully done this without changing the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually gave up on this process and ended with Citadel 8 on Slackware 14.0 with Postfix handling SMTP connections